# How to run a function in the background after my django website starts?

Tags: python, django

I have written an algorithm. And when I use `python manage.py runserver`, my website will run on the local server.

Now I want to run my algorithm after `python manage.py runserver`.

In other words, when I start the django website, I hope the algorithm will run in the background until it is completed. And I want to know if the algorithm is still running or the algorithm is complete.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **something like this:**

```
def function_that_downloads(my_args):
    # do some he

re

def __init__(self, function_that_downloads):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.runnable = function_that_downloads
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        self.runnable()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your solution to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you might want to checkout [Django Celery Beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) so later you can just define some task inside your Django Application and execute your function periodically

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')

    # Calls test('world') every 30 seconds
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, test.s('world'), expires=10)

    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Mondays!'),
    )

@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)from celery import Celery
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your solution to solve my problem.